# Populating RecyclerView with two sets of data from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have Firebase set up as so...

```
{
  "items" : {
    "-LDJak_gdBhZQ0NSB-7B" : { //item
      "name" : "Test123",
       ...
    },
    ...
  },
  "likes" : {
    "YoTjkR2ORlcr5hGedzQs5xOK2VE3" : { //user
      "-LDJiY0YSraa_RhxVWXL" : true //whether or not the item is liked
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

And I'm populating a `RecyclerView` with items, but I need to know if each item has been liked by the current user. I know I could store each user who has liked an item in the item itself, but that seems like too much repetition. But even if done that way, I'd have to check through a list of users who liked an item for that specific user, for each item added. Should I just live with all of this repetition or is there an easy way to deal with this? Here's the code I have that uses `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`:

```
private fun setUpFirebaseAdapter() {
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        val itemQuery = ref
                .child("items")
                .limitToLast(20)

        val itemOptions = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Item>()
                .setQuery(itemQuery, Item::class.java)
                .build()


        firebaseAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Item, FirebaseViewHolder>(itemOptions) {

            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FirebaseViewHolder {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false)

                return FirebaseViewHolder(view)
            }

            override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FirebaseViewHolder, position: Int, model: Item) {
                holder.bindItems(model)
                //...
            }
        }
    }
```

I know there's index support, but I think that would only allow me to only return liked items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But that seems like too much repetition.

Yes, it is.

> Should I just live with all of this repetition or is there an easy way to deal with this?

Yes, you should!

In such cases as yours, you should use this tehnique which is named in Firebase `denormalization`, and for that I recomend you see this tutorial, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA), for a better understanding.

So, there is nothing wrong in what you are doing, besides that is a common practice when it comes to Firebase.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Curious, though, wouldn't it be quite inefficient loading all of the keys for likes of each item just to search for one value on each? Maybe this is just one of the downsides to using nosql

Comment: Yes it is inefficient that why you should duplicate data so you can query only for specific data.